# Delete Backup files Older than 5 days?

Tags: vba, datetime

I can't figure out how to delete these excel files programmatically, say when they are 5 days(5 working days) old or older. I was able to figure out how to delete them if they are 5 days older then current date but the weekends and holiday, etc. leave some
undeleted.

Any help will be greatly appreciated,

here is code for backup excel files.

```
Dim backupfolder As String
    backupfolder = "E:/CLIENTS/ExcelBackup/BackupJM/"

Dim savedate
    savedate = Date ' Current system date

Dim savetime
    savetime = Time ' Current system time

Dim formattime As String
    formattime = Format(savetime, "hh.mm.ss")

 Dim formatdate As String
    formatdate = Format(savedate, "DD-MM-YYYY")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Application.Run ("Auto_Save")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fileName:=backupfolder & formatdate & " " & formattime & " " & 

ActiveWorkbook.Name

 ActiveWorkbook.Save

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 MsgBox "Backup Run. Please Check at: " & backupfolder
```

Comment: You should probably show the code you have that deletes them currently, it should be a simple fix to exclude non-working days (holidays are probably going to be where it get's complicated).